# Find element within element

Tags: typescript, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to find an element within a specific element.

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div>
     <label>test</label>
     <div>
          <a>testlink</a>
          <input type='text'></input>
          <textarea></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have the label based on its text, and I am trying to get the input under its sibling. I was first thinking of hardcoding it, but then noticed we sometimes have an extra layer under the sibling div, like this.

```
<div>
     <label>test</label>
     <div>
          <div>
              <a>testlink</a>
              <input type='text'></input>
              <textarea></textarea>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What I have tried is:

```
const labelElement = await Selector('label').withText('test')
const inputField = labelElement.sibling('div').find('input').withAttribute('type', 'text')
```

Problem is that I am getting back all inputs back on the page, not only this one. I guess that is what **find** does.

Is there any way to only get my required input?

Answer (score 2):

`Selector.sibling()` returns *elements*, `Selector.find()` returns nodes. Both can return more than just one "things".

I'd try to use [`Selector.nth()`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/nth.html), e.g.:

```js
const labelElement = await Selector('label').withText('test')
const inputField = labelElement.sibling('div').nth(0).find('input').withAttribute('type', 'text')
```